# c# console loading animation

Tags: c#, animation

So..
I want to make a loading animation in c# (/-\|). I've tried stuff and it semi worked. I got the animation working, but after every charakter change (eg. / -> -) the line drops one down.
idk why its so difficult to put the cursor one line up, but i just cant find anything.
Below is a sniped of code, for all 4 characters the same, in a for loop.

```
Console.Write("/");
Thread.Sleep(300);
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
Console.Write(new String(' ', Console.BufferWidth));
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
Console.Write("-");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var loaderChars = new[] { '/', '-', '\\', '|' };
var a = 0;

while (true)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
    Console.Write(loaderChars[a++]);
    a = a == loaderChars.Length ? 0 : a;
    Thread.Sleep(300);
}
```

Comment: As you like _tricks_: A neat trick is also `a = a % loaderChars.Length;` it will also tackle a +2

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen nice one, i'll take note of this :)